# Change the position dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, uitextview

Im new to IOS development , so when i change the width of a UITextFeild dynamically i want the button below to shift up . 
i tried using the constrains but it doesn't seem to shift dynamically .

```
 (IBAction)selectStatus:(id)sender {
    CGRect frameRect = _textViewDevices.frame;
    frameRect.size.height = 10; 
    self.textViewDevices.frame = frameRect;
```

any good example of how to achieve that ?

I want to achieve something like the Relative positioning in android .

[current box before any action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2nMW.jpg)
[image: on action the box size change]

Comment: Please, share some images how it should be and it is instead

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Do you have a constraint for the vertical spacing between the status button and the textView?

Comment: @ViktorSimkó yes i have

Comment: @SarahMaher, did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` after the modifications:

```
- (IBAction)selectStatus:(id)sender {
    CGRect frameRect = _textViewDevices.frame;
    frameRect.size.height = 10; 
    self.textViewDevices.frame = frameRect;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

If you have a height constraint on the text view, try to set its constant instead of setting the frame height:

```
- (IBAction)selectStatus:(id)sender {
    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = 10;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically when the first violet field changes in height, to make all the below views stay next to it, you should update the `frame.origin.y` properly.

So, for example, the status label should be reframed like this

```
CGRect frame = statusLabel.frame;
frame.origin.y = firstField.origin.y + firstField.size.height + 5;
statusLabel.frame = frame;
```

And the same for all below views (I've supposed 5 pixels of space between views)